# iOS Application Support Directory files overwritten on update?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

If I have a file called `file.txt` in Application Support Directory, then I release an update to AppStore for the app which has an update for `file.txt`. The users who update the app will they still have a reference to the old `file.txt` or will it be overwritten by the updated `file.txt`?

Comment: How do you copy the file into the support directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During an update you can expect the following:

1. The app's resource bundle is completely replaced.
2. The tmp and Caches directory may be purged (or not - this isn't documented).
3. The rest of the app's sandbox is kept as-is. This includes the Documents and Library folders (minus tmp and Caches).

So the only way the `file.txt` file will be overwritten during an update is if your app deliberately overwrites the file the first time the app is run after update.